# How to Enable TLS 1.2 on Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8

Tags: ios, web-services, ssl, authentication, ssl-certificate

Nowadays there are a SSL vulnerability called POODLE discovered by Google team in SSLv3 protocol. So uses of SSLv3 is not secure to use. Now its recommended to use TLS 1.2. We have IOS applications that are using web services over SSL for login to app. Apps started throwing error as iOS 10 they have mandated TLS 1.2, due to which we are getting error.

I have tried following script to update to TLS 1.2, but still having login issue.

```
# Copyright 2014, Alexander Hass
# http://www.hass.de/content/setup-your-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12
#
# Version 1.4
# - RC4 has been disabled.
# Version 1.3
# - MD5 has been disabled.
# Version 1.2
# - Re-factored code style and output
# Version 1.1
# - SSLv3 has been disabled. (Poodle attack protection)

Write-Host 'Configuring IIS with SSL/TLS Deployment Best Practices...'
Write-Host '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

# Disable Multi-Protocol Unified Hello
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'Multi-Protocol Unified Hello has been disabled.'

# Disable PCT 1.0
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'PCT 1.0 has been disabled.'

# Disable SSL 2.0 (PCI Compliance)
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'SSL 2.0 has been disabled.'

# NOTE: If you disable SSL 3.0 the you may lock out some people still using
# Windows XP with IE6/7. Without SSL 3.0 enabled, there is no protocol available
# for these people to fall back. Safer shopping certifications may require that
# you disable SSLv3.
#
# Disable SSL 3.0 (PCI Compliance) and enable "Poodle" protection
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'SSL 3.0 has been disabled.'

# Add and Enable TLS 1.0 for client and server SCHANNEL communications
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'TLS 1.0 has been enabled.'

# Add and Enable TLS 1.1 for client and server SCHANNEL communications
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'TLS 1.1 has been enabled.'

# Add and Enable TLS 1.2 for client and server SCHANNEL communications
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'TLS 1.2 has been enabled.'

# Re-create the ciphers key.
New-Item 'HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers' -Force | Out-Null

# Disable insecure/weak ciphers.
$insecureCiphers = @(
  'DES 56/56',
  'NULL',
  'RC2 128/128',
  'RC2 40/128',
  'RC2 56/128',
  'RC4 40/128',
  'RC4 56/128',
  'RC4 64/128',
  'RC4 128/128'
)
Foreach ($insecureCipher in $insecureCiphers) {
  $key = (Get-Item HKLM:\).OpenSubKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers', $true).CreateSubKey($insecureCipher)
  $key.SetValue('Enabled', 0, 'DWord')
  $key.close()
  Write-Host "Weak cipher $insecureCipher has been disabled."
}

# Enable new secure ciphers.
# - RC4: It is recommended to disable RC4, but you may lock out WinXP/IE8 if you enforce this. This is a requirement for FIPS 140-2.
# - 3DES: It is recommended to disable these in near future.
$secureCiphers = @(
  'AES 128/128',
  'AES 256/256',
  'Triple DES 168/168'
)
Foreach ($secureCipher in $secureCiphers) {
  $key = (Get-Item HKLM:\).OpenSubKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers', $true).CreateSubKey($secureCipher)
  New-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\$secureCipher" -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
  $key.close()
  Write-Host "Strong cipher $secureCipher has been enabled."
}

# Set hashes configuration.
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\MD5' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\MD5' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\SHA' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\SHA' -name Enabled -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

# Set KeyExchangeAlgorithms configuration.
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\Diffie-Hellman' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\Diffie-Hellman' -name Enabled -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\PKCS' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\PKCS' -name Enabled -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

# Set cipher suites order as secure as possible (Enables Perfect Forward Secrecy).
$cipherSuitesOrder = @(
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P521',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P521',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P521',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P521',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384',
  'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P521',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P521',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P384',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P256',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P521',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P521',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P521',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P521',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384',
  'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256',
  'TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256',
  'TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA',
  'TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256',
  'TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA',
  'TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA',
  'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256',
  'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA',
  'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256',
  'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA',
  'TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA'
)
$cipherSuitesAsString = [string]::join(',', $cipherSuitesOrder)
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002' -name 'Functions' -value $cipherSuitesAsString -PropertyType 'String' -Force | Out-Null

Write-Host '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Write-Host 'NOTE: After the system has been rebooted you can verify your server'
Write-Host '      configuration at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/'
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------`n"

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'A computer restart is required to apply settings. Restart computer now?'
Restart-Computer -Force -Confirm
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a programming question appropriate for stack overflow. Perhaps http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com would be better.